Language Studio - how to move training info from test to production?
I have a question and answer bot that I setup in our test environment. Once I have it working, I export the QnAs to a TSV file, import them into our production environment, and deploy that project. I never make changes directly to the production environment. (I do this with a powershell script in our deployment ipeline - not manually)
I now have a question and answer bot that I need to train, using the Review suggestions tab of language studio. I've trianed it in the test environment, but I don't know how to get the training info to prod. I don't want to train it directly in production, because that would require releasing untrained questions and answers for a period of time
It doesn't look like the training data is in the Q&A export.
How can I train in test, and get the training data to production?
